# Unexpected syntax error in MIPS assembly code

Tags: assembly, syntax, branch, mips

I'm new to the MIPS language and am trying to teach myself for this part of my homework assignment. I'm using QTSpim to run the code, and the syntax error I'm getting is at line 18 (I marked it with -->). The parser just points to the end of that line.

The intention of the code is to find the max value in arrayA through iteration. If anyone could help explain to me why this error is occurring I would greatly appreciate it.

```
 .data
    arrayA: .word   5, 2, 4, 7, 14, 10, 3, 17, 11, 19
    arrayB: .word   15, 16, 8, 1, 6, 12, 13, 9, 20, 18
    arrayC: .space 40
    arrayD: .space 40
    .text

    .globl main
    main:   
        li  $t3, 40             #t3 will hold size of array
        li  $t0, 0              #t0 will be incremented index 
        lw  $t1, arrayA($t0)        #t1 is the first value in A and will eventually be the max
        lw  $t2, arrayB($t0)        #t2 is the first value in B and will eventually be the max
    findMAX:
        lw  $t4, arrayA($t0)        #current value of A stored in t4
        blt $t4, $t1, skip          #if current value of A is less than stored max, then skip next line
 ---->  lw  $t1, $t4            #(runs if current value is = or > stored max) stores new max
    skip:
        addi    $t0, $t0, 4         #increment t0
        blt $t0, $t3, findMAX       #if t0 is not at the end of the array, then continue search

        li  $v0, 1              #allow syscall to print int stored in a0
        move    $a0, $t1            #store new found max in a0
        syscall                 #print max
```

Comment: `lw  $t1, $t4` should be `move  $t1, $t4`

Comment: OH, now I understand the move call. Thank you so much.